# integration of a list of functions in Matlab

Tags: matlab

How can I use `integral` over a list of functions. The code below doesn't work:

```
integral(@(v) exp(-v*[1 2 3]),0,100)
```

`exp(-v*[1 2 3])` is the list of functions.

The code is inside another function with the vector `[1 2 3]` as input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to used the name-value pair ([`'ArrayValued',true`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html#input_argument_namevalue_arrayvalued)) for non-scalar functions (this is because for scalar integrands, the function passes vectors of integration points to the integrand function in conjunction with `bsxfun` for speed).

```
>> integral(@(v) exp(-v*[1 2 3]),0,100,'ArrayValued',true)

ans =
1.0000    0.5000    0.3333
```

---

I'd also note that `integral` can handle `Inf` as an upper-bound if that is what `100` is approximating:

```
>> integral(@(v) exp(-v*[1 2 3]),0,Inf,'ArrayValued',true)

ans =
1.0000    0.5000    0.3333
```

While the outputs look similar, this one is accurate to machine-precision.

Comment: Thank you. Especially the remark on infinity as the upper limit.